# execl only executing once in a forked process, C programming

Tags: c, exec, fork

For some reason that I am unaware of, my only my first execl statement is executing in the following code:

```
pid = fork();
if(pid < 0){
    fprintf(stderr, "Fork Failed.\n");
    exit(1);
    return;
}else if(pid==0){
        if(execl("/home/tropix/hw11-2","/home/tropix/hw11-2",semarg,pipe_to_p3,pipe_to_p4,(char*)0)){
            fprintf(stderr, "File Exexecution of hw11-2 failed.\n");
            exit(1);
        }
        if(execl("/home/tropix/hw11-3","/home/tropix/hw11-3",shmarg,semarg,pipe_from_p2,pipe_to_p5_1, (char*)0)){
            fprintf(stderr, "File Execution of hw11-3 failed.\n");
            exit(1);
        }
        if(execl("/home/tropix/hw11-4","/home/tropix/hw11-4",shmarg,semarg,pipe_from_p2_2,pipe_to_p5_2, (char*)0)){
            fprintf(stderr, "File Execution of hw11-4 failed.\n");
            exit(1);
        }
        if(execl("/home/tropix/hw11-5","/home/tropix/hw11-5",semarg,pipe_from_p3,pipe_from_p4,(char*)0)){
            fprintf(stderr, "File Execution of hw11-5 failed.\n");
            exit(1);
        }
} else (...parent stuff...)
```

Does anyone have an idea as to why this is?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[The exec family of functions shall replace the current process image with a new process image.](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/exec.html)

So, after the 1st `execl`, the 2nd does simply not exist.

Comment: Any suggestions on a solution then? Am I forced to use system()?

Comment: you can `fork` 3 more times in the /* parent stuff */ ... :)

Answer (score 2):

The `exec` family of functions work by replacing your process with the one you specify, so the function never returns if it is successful.

Answer (score 0):

As the other answers say, `exec*` replace the current process image with a new one, so you need to `fork()` once for every `exec*()` if you want to spawn several children processes.